# Is it possible to (quickly) find only the first cycle in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, cycle

I have a directed network that may or may not have cycles in it. I need to find them and remove the cyclicity. If I have a networkx DiGraph (G), I can find all the cycles with

```
cycle_nodes = nx.simple_cycles(G)
```

which creates a cycle-returning generator.

However, I don't want to return all cycles a la `list(cycle_nodes)` because many of the cycles are subsets of each other, and fixing one will fix others. Instead, I would like to only find the first instance of a cycle. As `cycle_nodes` is a generator, I tried

```
next(cycle_nodes)
```

to return only the first instance. However, I found that the time required to return the first instance not much smaller compared to the time required to return all instances:

```
list(cycle_nodes) : 58s
next(cycle_nodes) : 44s
```

Is this just due to the nature of my graph (i.e. the first cycle is far along the search order), or is there a more efficient way to return any cycle (doesn't necessarily need to be the first)?

The reason I suspect there may be a faster way is because when I run `nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G)`, it takes only a second or two and returns False, so it's obviously finding at least one cycle in just a second or so.

Comment: I think the issue is that `simple_cycles` has the following two commands at the beginning: `subG = type(G)(G.edges())` and `sccs = list(nx.strongly_connected_components(subG))`.  So it has created a new graph and found all strongly connected components before it looks for the first cycle.  So all that overhead is probably the issue.  In contrast, the test for if it's acyclic tries to do a "topological sort".  So there's probably an opportunity to speed things up (perhaps by finding strongly connected components and then focusing on cycles in each one in turn).

Comment: @Joel Unfortunately, those two lines take well under a second to run. But I didn't even think of looking through the source code myself, so thanks for reminding me. I'll check out is_directed_acyclic_graph to see if I can get it to return the cycle it found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was sort of obvious. The algorithm nx.find_cycle() with no starting node provided will return the first cycle it finds, and rapidly. I was under the impression that a starting node needed to be provided, RTFM!